# Batch File to Delete Files in Folders

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have many folders in a directory that contain various files.  Each filename begins with XXX_ where XXX could be the name of the folder the file is in.  What I am needing to do is to go through all those folders and delete any file where XXX is the name of the folder that file is in.

Comment: You mean, delete any file(s) under the directories which filename starts with `XXX_`?

Comment: Yeah the beginning of the file until the _ would equal the folder name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have an eye out this question: [`Iterating through folders and files in batch file?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999640/iterating-through-folders-and-files-in-batch-file).

I think this should help you.

Please let me know if you need further assistance.

**EDIT #1**

The joker character in DOS command line is `*`. Then, while searching a directory for certain files, you may consider your regular expression, that is, your `XXX_`, and complete it with `*`, this shall return only the files for which you're looking for.

This means that instead of `*.zip` pattern in one of the `FOR` loops given the linked question, your first `FOR` loop should contain your directory name, then take this variable concatenated with the `*` character to obtain only the files you're looking for.

For example, consider trying the following:

```
dir /s XXX_*.*
```

This should return only the files you're interested in, given the right folder name.

**EDIT #2**

Thanks for having precised your concern.

Here is a code sample that, I do hope so, should help. Now I  know you say you have the looping correct, so that perhaps only piece of this code might be needed.

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "delims==" %%d in ('dir /ogne /ad /b /s .') do (
    for /F "delims==" %%f in ('dir /b "%%d\%%~nd_*.*"') do (
        echo %%d\%%f
    )
)

endlocal
```

This works and lists the files contained in subfolders from the current (`.`) folder.

I have tested it from the following folder:

> C:\Docume~1\marw1\MyDocu~1\MyMusi~1

Where a 'XXX' folder is contained. This 'XXX' folder contains the following files:

> 1. Copy of XXX_blah.bmp;
> 2. XXX_blah.bmp;
> 3. XXX_1234.ppt;
> 4. XXX_textfile.txt.

From this structure, the output is:

> C:\Docume~1\marw1\MyDocu~1\MyMusi~1\XXX\XXX_blah.bmp
>   C:\Docume~1\marw1\MyDocu~1\MyMusi~1\XXX\XXX_1234.ppt
>   C:\Docume~1\marw1\MyDocu~1\MyMusi~1\XXX\XXX_textfile.txt

I then suspect that putting a `del` instruction instead of an `echo` command shall do the trick. This means that to isolate the foldername itself from its path, you need to use the `~n` instruction with your folder variable name like `%%~nd`, where your iterating folder variable name is `%%d`.

Furthermore, you could even use a parameterized batch file in the process, instead of hardcoding it, that is, if your `'set YourFolder =...'` is part of your production code. This could look like:

```
@echo off

setlocal...

set root = %1
set root = %root:~1%
set root = %root:~0,-1%

...

endlocal
```

Instead of having `'.'` as pictured in my first `FOR` loop, your would replace it with `"%root%"` in order to consider your command line parameter instead of a hardcoded filepath.

I do help this helps, sincerely!

Comment: Not really what I want to do.  I really just need a script to delete the file if it contains the folder name it is in.  I can script the rest to do it to the whole directory myself.

Comment: How do I match XXX to the folder name I have the whole loop written I just do not know how to write if or where xxx folder == xxx from begining of filename?

Comment: @echo off
set YourFolder=D:\MAPPS\file_processing\computers
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /a:-d /b /s "%YourFolder%\*.server_outgoing"') do (
pushd %%~dpA
for %%b in (.) if not "%%A"=="%%~nb" do del *.server_outgoing
popd)

Comment: AWESOME, this was a tail end of a huge project I have been working on and just needed to move these files to finish processing them.  You rock dude and made my day with the help!  Here is the final code I used:

Comment: @echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "delims==" %%d in ('dir /ad /b /s "%YourFolder%"') do (
    for /F "delims==" %%f in ('dir /b "%%d\%%~nd*.*"') do (
        del %%d\%%f
    )
)

endlocal

Comment: I'm glad I could help! I can feel your gratitude with this "AWESOME" comment. Thanks for having accepted my answer. You may even upvote! =)

Answer (score 0):

As Ron says, since the question is tagged "windows".

**EDIT:**

Ron's answer, which seems to have disappeared!, was to use `del /s`

**EDIT2:**

OK, it's valid only for *file* names, not for directories. For the directories you'd have to use something like sketched below.

Additional info: when you want to do the same thing recursively to files in a directory tree, and (unlike `del`) there's no command that already does the traversing for you, you can use the `/R` option of the `for` command.

To see the `for` command's docs, do e.g. `start "for-help" cmd /k for /?`.

Cheers & hth.,

– Alf

Comment: I didn't see Ron's answer so I'm not really understanding yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd C:\"foldername"
del /s XXX_"*"
cls
exit
```